Why my async function seems not to run asynchronously?
I want to (quickly) scan my LAN to find a host listening to a certain TCP port, e.g. 2442 (JS8Call network API, if anyone's interested).
I copied program structure from a tutorial explaining asynchronous execution in python with the help of asyncio package. The program kind of works, but the individual tasks do not run in parallel, instead they run in sequence although the task creation and result collection seems to be OK. When it runs, I can see the print messages from async function ping appearing sequentially, the next one always appearing exactly after the previous one timed out.
What is wrong with my ping function? It does not seem to create a coroutine object, I guess.
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import asyncio

socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.5)

async def ping(host, port):
  r = f'{host}:{port} OK'
  try:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
      s.connect( (host, port) )
      print( r )
      s.close()
      return r
  except Exception as X:
    print(f'{host} FAILED')
    return X

async def main():
  tasks = []
  async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
    # start all tasks
    for i in range(5,240):
      host = f'192.168.33.{i}'
      t = tg.create_task( ping(host, 22) )
      tasks.append(t)
  results = [ task.result() for task in tasks ]
  for p in results:
    if p != None:
      print(p)

asyncio.run( main() )


You never use await within ping(), therefore there is no chance for python to hand off to another task.

I changed the line with s.connect((host, port)) to await asyncio.create_task( s.connect((host,port))) but it did not help. I have no problem achieving the desired behavior in nodejs, but python seems to use some strange logic I cannot capture.

The argument to create_task() should be an async function call. s.connect() is synchronous.

I think I would need to use 'asynchronous version' of s.connect((host, port)) because that is the call that blocks, but I cannot find any documentation explaining what is the asynchronous (non-blocking) version of socket.connect() or how to turn the blocking function into a promise. In javascript all blocking I/O yields to the event loop  whenever it is not ready to actually receive or send data, but in python it seems only specific functions in asyncio package can run asynchronously and whatever else is the old style blocking I/O whatever happens.

So in fact the asyncio package actually does not solve the problem of asynchronous I/O, it rather imitates it could do such a thing.

See https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams use asyncio.open_connection()

@Barmar thank you, this is what I was looking for. Kind of hidden under a slightly misleading header but it is there. I don't quite understand why none of the tutorials or examples I got from search even mentions this.

I found it in a couple of steps. I googled "python async sockets", it sent me to asyncore. This said it was deprecated, and had a link to asyncio. There I followed the link for "perform network IO and IPC", which is the above URL.
